# undefined property stdclass::$metadata

Tags: php

I'm getting **undefined property stdclass::$metadata** when I'm trying to fetch data from WHM packages.

I'm getting this when validating server id

My code

```
@push('script')
    <script>
        (function($){
            "use strict"; 
    
            $('select[name=server_group]').on('change', function(){
                var id = $(this).val();
                
                if(!id){
                    return false;
                }
    
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'post',
                    url: '{{ route("admin.get.whm.package") }}',
                    data: {
                        '_token': '{{ csrf_token() }}',
                        'server_group_id': id
                    },
                    beforeSend: function(){
                        $('.spinner-border').removeClass('d-none');
                    },
                    complete: function(){
                        $('.spinner-border').addClass('d-none');
                    }, 
                    success: function (response){
               
                        $('select[name=package_name] option:not(:first)').remove();
             
                        if(response.success){ 
                            Object.entries(response.data).forEach(function(data, index){
                                data[1].forEach(function(value){
                                    var name = value.split('_').pop();
                                    $('select[name=package_name]').append($('<option>', {value: value, text: value}).attr('data-server_id', data[0]));
                                });
                            });
                        }else{
                            notify('error', response.message);
                        }
                    },
    
                });
    
            });
    
            $('select[name=package_name]').on('change', function(){
                var serverId = $(this).children('option:selected').data('server_id');
                $('.server_id').val(serverId);
            });
    
            var form = $('.form-horizontal');
    
            var oldProductType = '{{ old("product_type") }}';
            var oldCategory = '{{ old("service_category") }}';
    
            if(oldProductType){
                $('select[name=product_type]').val(oldProductType);
            }
            if(oldCategory){
                $('select[name=service_category]').val(oldCategory);
                $('.categorySlug').text($('select[name=service_category]').find(':selected').data('slug')+'/');
            } 
    
            form.find('select[name=module_type]').on('change',  function(){
                var value = $(this).val();
                
                if(value == 0){
                    $('select[name=server_group]').prop('disabled', true);
                    $('select[name=package_name]').prop('disabled', true);  
                    return form.find('input[name=module_option]').prop({
                        'disabled': true,
                        'checked': true
                    });
                }
                
                $('select[name=server_group]').prop('disabled', false);
                $('select[name=package_name]').prop('disabled', false);
                return form.find('input[name=module_option]').prop({
                    'disabled': false
                });
            }).change();
    
            form.find('select[name=service_category]').on('change',  function(){
                var value = $(this).val();
                
                if(value){
    
                    form.find('.readonly').prop('readonly', true);
                    var name = form.find('input[name=name]').val();
                    var slug = form.find('input[name=slug]').val();
    
                    if(slug){
                        checkSlug(slug, makeSlug(slug), value);
                    }else if(name){
                        checkSlug(name, makeSlug(name), value);
                    }
                    
                    $('.categorySlug').text($(this).find(':selected').data('slug')+'/');
                    return form.find('.readonly').prop('readonly', false);
                }
    
                form.find('.readonly').prop('readonly', true);
    
            }).change();
    
            var slugRule = /^[0-9a-zA-Z -]+$/;
    
            form.find('input[name=name]').on('input',  function(){
                var input = $(this).val();
                var slug = makeSlug(input);
                var category = $('select[name=service_category]').val();
    
                if(!category){
                    return notify('info', 'Please select service category');
                }
    
                if(input.match(slugRule)){
                    form.find('input[name=slug]').val(slug);
                    return checkSlug(input, slug, category);
                }
            });
    
            form.find('input[name=slug]').on('input',  function(){
                var input = $(this).val();
                var slug = makeSlug(input);
                var category = $('select[name=service_category]').val();
    
                if(!category){
                    return notify('info', 'Please select service category');
                }
    
                if(input.match(slugRule)){
                    $(this).val(slug); 
                    return checkSlug(input, slug, category);
                }
            });
    
            function makeSlug(input){
                return input.toLowerCase().replace(/ /g,'-').replace(/[^\w-]+/g,'');
            }
    
            function checkSlug(input, slug, category){
                $.ajax({
                    type:'POST',
                    url:'{{ route("admin.check.slug") }}',
                    data: {
                        'input': input,
                        'model_type': 'product',
                        'category_id': category,
                        '_token': '{{ csrf_token() }}',
                    },
    
                    beforeSend: function() {
                        $('.slugValidatation').removeClass('d-none');
                        $('.slugValidatation').addClass('d-inline');
                        $('.slugIcon').html('<i class="fas fa-spinner fa-spin"></i>');
                        $('.ajaxResponse').text('Validating...');
                    }, 
    
                    success:function(response){
                        setTimeout(function() { 
                            if(response.error){
                                $.each(response.error, function(key, value) {
                                    notify('error', value);
                                });
                                $('.slugValidatation').addClass('d-none');
                                $('.slugValidatation').removeClass('d-inline');
                            } 
                            else if(!response.success){
                                $('.productSlug').text(slug);
                                $('.slugIcon').html('');
                                var message = `<span class='text--danger'>${response.message}</span>`;
                                return $('.ajaxResponse').html(message);
                            }
                            else if(response.success){
                                $('.ajaxResponse').text('');
                                $('.slugIcon').html('');
                                return $('.productSlug').text(slug);
                            }
                        }, 300);
                    }
                });
            }
    
        })(jQuery);    
        </script> 
    @endpush
    
    
    @push('style')
    <style>
        .slugUrl span{ 
            border-bottom: 1px dashed;
        }
        .slugUrl{ 
            font-size: 14px;
        }
        .defaultLabel {
            font-size: initial;
        } 
        .text-dot{  
            height: inherit; 
        }
    </style>
    @endpush
```

Thanks

Comment: Why is this tagged for PHP when you have absolutely no PHP code shown here?

Answer (score -1):

The error message "undefined property stdclass::$metadata" suggests that the response you're receiving from the server does not contain the expected "metadata" property. This error occurs when you're trying to access a property that doesn't exist in the response object.

To debug this issue, you can examine the response you're receiving from the server by logging it to the console or inspecting it in the browser's network tab. Here are a few steps you can take to identify the problem:

Open your web browser's developer tools (usually accessed by pressing F12) and go to the "Console" tab.
Trigger the AJAX request by performing the action that triggers it on your page.
Look for the response in the console. It should display the actual JSON data returned by the server.
Check if the response object contains a "metadata" property. You can expand the object in the console to inspect its structure.
Based on the code you provided, it seems that the response object should have a "metadata" property that you're trying to access. You can modify your success callback to handle cases where the "metadata" property is not present in the response:

```
success: function(response) {
    $('select[name=package_name] option:not(:first)').remove();

    if (response.success) {
        if (response.hasOwnProperty('metadata')) {
            // Process the metadata if it exists
            // You can access it using response.metadata
        }

        Object.entries(response.data).forEach(function(data, index) {
            data[1].forEach(function(value) {
                var name = value.split('_').pop();
                $('select[name=package_name]').append($('<option>', {
                    value: value,
                    text: value
                }).attr('data-server_id', data[0]));
            });
        });
    } else {
        notify('error', response.message);
    }
}
```

In the modified code, we added a check using response.hasOwnProperty('metadata') to verify if the "metadata" property exists before attempting to access it. This will prevent the "undefined property" error from occurring.

By examining the actual response object, you should be able to determine the structure and properties present in the response and adjust your code accordingly to handle them appropriately.

Comment: This answer looks like it was generated by an AI (like ChatGPT), not by an actual human being. You should be aware that [posting AI-generated output is officially **BANNED** on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If this answer was indeed generated by an AI, then I strongly suggest you delete it before you get yourself into even bigger trouble: **WE TAKE PLAGIARISM SERIOUSLY HERE.** Please read: [Why posting GPT and ChatGPT generated answers is not currently allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy).